# Postgres partial index not taken into acount

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table with ~200 million rows. On that table, I have a flag `deprecated` (boolean) and a `date_time` (timestamp).

My table is filled with deprecated values. At the moment I have 3 values on the 200 million that are not deprecated.

So I tried to add a partial index on the deprecated flag, but postgres does not take it into consideration and keep doing a Seq scan.

Here is how the index was created:

```
CREATE INDEX api_kpi_date_time_idx ON public.api_kpi USING btree (date_time) WHERE (deprecated = false)
```

And I try to run an explain:

```
explain select ak.id from api_kpi ak
where ak.deprecated is false and date_time < now()
```

I get the following:

```
Seq Scan on api_kpi ak  (cost=0.00..10208288.72 rows=80594624 width=37)
  Filter: ((deprecated IS FALSE) AND (date_time < now()))
```

And the query takes almost 5 minutes to run.

What do I need to do to make sure that Postgres takes the index into consideration and only do the date comparison on the subset from the index?

Comment: Is the `deprecated` column NULLable? Did you run ANALYZE after adding the index?

Comment: Found the issue..... deprecated IS FALSE is not picked up by the index. But deprecated = FALSE is.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the error after playing with the query.

`deprecated IS FALSE` != `deprecated = FALSE`. When creating a partial index, the query has to be exactly the same for Postgres to pick it up.